# How to 'dynamically render' HTML elements with PHP else/if statements?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am attempting to display the correct HTML under a "p" tag with PHP based on a true/false value which is pulled from WordPress ACF plugin, for every individual post. It's my first time using PHP and I'm not sure how to go about this.

My code is:

```
<p class="applied-grid-filter">
     <?php if (the_field('relocation', $job->ID) === 1) ?>
 </p>
```

Currently, if the post has "relocation" marked as false - an empty applied-grid-filter "p" tag appears. If the post has "relocation" marked as true - an applied-grid-filter "p" tag with the number "1" for true appears.

How can I make it so that when it is marked false, no P tag is made at all - and when the post is marked true, a P tag with textcontent of "Relocation" is made?

edit full context:

```
<section class="job-search-grid">
<?php if (count($jobs)) { ?>
    <div class="job-search-grid-container">
        <?php foreach ($jobs as $job) { ?>
            <div class="job-search-grid-item">
                <h2 class="job-search-grid-title"><?= esc_html($job->post_title) ?></h2>
                <div class="salary-location-container">
                    <h2 class="job-search-grid-salary"><?php the_field('minimum_salary', $job->ID) ?>K
                        - <?php the_field('maximum_salary', $job->ID) ?>K</h2>
                    <div class="job-search-location-icon-container">
                        <img
                                class="job-search-location-icon"
                                src="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/location-icon.png"
                        />
                        <p class="job-search-grid-location">Louisville, KY</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="job-search-grid-description">
                    <?php the_field('short_description', $job->ID) ?>
                </p>
                <div class="applied-grid-filters">
                    <?php foreach (get_terms('industry', ['object_id' => $job->ID]) as $term) { ?>
                        <p class="applied-grid-filter"><?= esc_html($term->name) ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php foreach (get_terms('job_type', ['object_id' => $job->ID]) as $term) { ?>
                        <p class="applied-grid-filter"><?= esc_html($term->name) ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php
                    if (the_field('relocation', $job->ID) === 1) { ?>
                        <p class="applied-grid-filter">Relocation</p>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php
                    if (the_field('travel', $job->ID) === 0) { ?>
                        <p class="applied-grid-filter">No Travel</p>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
                <a class="job-view-more" href="<?php the_permalink($job->ID) ?>">View More</a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p class="no-results">No results found! Try another search.</p>
<?php } ?></section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the html code inside your php code. You also might wanna use `get_field` instead of `the_field`. Also consider using the `equal ==` instead of the `identical ===` comparison operator which will be tolerant if the return value is not a number but for example `true/false`.

Also have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for this.

```
<?php 
if (get_field('relocation', $job->ID) == 1) { ?>
<p class="applied-grid-filter"></p>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: I tried that - but then just a "1" appears (if true) or nothing appears if not true, and with no CSS styling (so the "applied-grid-filter" style is not being applied)

Comment: What does `the_field('relocation', $job->ID)`return?

Comment: If I var_dump it, it returns NULL if it is unchecked. If it's checked, it returns 1NULL

Comment: Can you post your code you tried? For me it looks fine.#

Comment: I edited the full context of the section to the original post. Everything works as intended except these true/false filters (relocation, location) and I don't know why.

Comment: have you tried with `get_field` instead `the_field`?

Comment: @Gabriel according to ACF `the_field` is equivalent to `echo get_field` so you don't want to echo that in the check there. Your `1` there is probably the return value of the function call - php sometimes returns the state of the function call.

Comment: sorry, nothing fits together on your post. Your initial code is nowhere to find in your last edit

Comment: @F.Müller PHP will display the return value of the function, but not if it is used in an if-statement as stated in the initial post

Comment: @JimPanse The initial code is the same as the last edit, except the if statements are like this: 

<p class="applied-grid-filter">
     <?php if (the_field('relocation', $job->ID) === 1) ?>
 </p>

and when the if statements are like that - at least the "applied grid filter" styles are being applied to the "p" tag

Comment: @Alvin If I use "get_field" - it doesn't seem to display anything, not even a 0 or 1

Comment: Honestyl, I am out. My code suggestions works ... if the condition meet the p tag is thrown. If it doesn't meet, nothing is thrown.

Comment: Do you confuse `<p class="job-search-grid-description"><?php the_field('short_description', $job->ID) ?></p>` ? This indeed returns 1 or nothing since there is no if like suggested in your initial post ...

Comment: No, the_field('short_description') returns the text of the short_description custom field and works fine. The 1 is coming from 'relocation' which is a true/false custom field type

Comment: But if its true or false you should also consider using the equal "==" operator instead of the idetical one "==="

Comment: Thank you Alvin and Jim. I managed to get it to work by using get_field instead of the_field and then equal operator instead of the strict equality operator. Also I was using the incorrect field for "location" - the selector I made should have been called 'travel.'

Comment: Thanks, i edited my answer to fit your actual solution.